# Distinct digits but Close Enough

Tags: mathematics

Using the digits from $1$ to $9$,

- Form four numbers, such as ($X$,$Y$,$Z$,$T$)
- Then take $X\div Y$ and $Z\div T$ where both values should be different than each other.
- You need to use all digits from $1$ to $9$ but once, such as ($923\div 85$,$67\div 41$)

> **What is the smallest difference between these two values?**

Comment: how many digits for each number, any restrictions?

Comment: Strange you accepted the answer that provided solution later.

Comment: @rus9384 what do you mean by solution later?

Comment: See when the edits were commited. Just hover your mouse over "edited x hours ago" link.

Comment: @rus9384 seems you are right, I missed the other one who provided the right answer before anyone else :) thanks

Comment: 1. Using *only* the digits from 1 to 9? 2. Using only concatenation to form X, Y, Z, and T?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My first attempt

> Staying close to the original order of numbers
>  `45/69 - 78/123`
>  `0.01802757`

No major breakthrough, just another attempt

> Keeping the top low and using ad odd number of total top digits
>  `12/987 - 5/436`
>  `0.000690164803`

Third

> `2/835 - 4/1679`
>  `0.00001283912223`

This one is pretty small

> Again keeping the top tiny and trying to keep the bottom factor as close to the factor on top
>  `1 / 826 - 9 / 7435`
>  `0.000000162831708`
>  `(7435 / 826 = 9.00121)`

Comment: I wrote a computer program, and your last solution seems to be the best possible.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis yes, I did the same and it doesn't get lower than that

Comment: As this one got smallest possible answer 1st I think this should be accepted

Comment: I feel I got a bit lucky here, as @Bass inspired my approach and the factor chosen was a bit arbitrary. Anyway, fun puzzle. It made quite a few people push for perfection, and the improvement of answers from different people was fun to see!

Comment: By the way, I took a look at all the non-answers where the difference is zero. These range from $1/8 - 954/7632=0$ where there is a factor of $954$ between their denominators or numerators, to $32/96 - 58/174=0$ where the factor is just below $2$.

Answer (score 10):

First attempt:

> Make two rational numbers, with one's numbers twice that of the others, small numbers on top, large numbers on the bottom:
>   $\frac{4}{763} - \frac{8}{1529} \approx .000010 $ (four zeroes after the decimal point)

Second attempt:

> Factor of three: $\frac{1}{954} - \frac{3}{2867} \approx .0000018 $ (five zeroes)

Third:

> $\frac{4}{3567} - \frac{1}{892} \approx .000000314 $ (six zeroes)

Fourth:

> $\frac{1}{826} - \frac{9}{7435} \approx .00000016 $ (still six zeroes)

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be

> 0.

This is because

> $\frac{1358}{4} - \frac{679}{2} = 0$.

Comment: "both values should be different than each other."

Comment: given that the values must be different, 0 seems unlikely.

Comment: Sorry gentlemen, I just can’t read!

Comment: though still thumps up, good one :)

Answer (score 5):

Joke answer.

> You guys are going about this all wrong. Clearly the answer is:
>  $$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{987654}{1} = -987653.333\ldots$$
>  This is much smaller than your near zero answers.

Comment: Hahahahahahaha. Hilarious! Good one! Although technically a whole number is a fraction, and he didn't say we can't do exponents, so, 1 - (9^8^7^6^5^4^3^2) is way better.

Answer (score 4):

Just by randomly mixing up different digits I came up with this

> $\dfrac{64}{8} - \dfrac{975}{123} = 0.0731707\dots$

Second try

> $\dfrac{124}{975} - \dfrac{8}{63} = 0.000195\dots$

Comment: You can do much better by using the reciprocal values.

Comment: @MOehm oh god, thats true, feel stupid now

Answer (score 2):

Here's My attempt-

> $\dfrac{975}{483} - \dfrac{12}{6} = 0.01863354\dots$